# Why I am not getting the value

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML is:

```
<urp>

    <pRespId>2345</pRespId>
    <pRespApplId>800</pRespApplId>
    <pSecurityGroupID>0</pSecurityGroupID>

</urp>
```

I am trying to populate some variable value using the below XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="pRespId" select="urp/pRespId" />
        <xsl:variable name="pRespApplId" select="urp/pRespApplId" />
        <xsl:variable name="pSecurityGroupID" select="urp/pSecurityGroupID" />
        <xsl:variable name="newURI" select = "'pRespId=$pRespId&amp;pRespApplId=$pRespApplId&amp;pSecurityGroupID=$pSecurityGroupID'"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But somehow I am not able to get the of pRespId, pRespApplId & pSecurityGroupID in newURI. It is always showing me

```
pRespId=$pRespId&pRespApplId=$pRespApplId&pSecurityGroupID=$pSecurityGroupID
```

Instead of:

```
pRespId=2345&pRespApplId=800&pSecurityGroupID=0
```

I know I am missing something in this line:

```
<xsl:variable name="newURI" select = "'pRespId=$pRespId&amp;pRespApplId=$pRespApplId&amp;pSecurityGroupID=$pSecurityGroupID'"
```

Can someone rectify what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `newURI` is just setting a string value. It is not going to evaluate any variable references in the string.

You could try using the `concat` function and have separate arguments for the variables you want to evaluate

```
<xsl:variable
     name="newURI" 
     select="concat('pRespId=', $pRespId, '&amp;pRespApplId=', $pRespApplId, '&amp;pSecurityGroupID=', $pSecurityGroupID)"/>
```